# "TBB library cannot be found" CMake on MacOS

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, cmake, tbb

I'm trying to build PrusaSlicer from source on Mac. I don't have any experience with CMake. I'm following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/prusa3d/PrusaSlicer/blob/version_2.4.2/doc/How%20to%20build%20-%20Mac%20OS.md).

Every time I try to build dependencies. This command `cmake ..`gives me errors. Earlier it was saying "Boost cannot be found." I fixed that by installing boost with brew. Now it's stuck on TBB.

```
OS X SDK Path: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk
  OS X Deployment Target: (default)
  -- Boost::boost exists
  CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
    TBB library cannot be found.  Consider set TBBROOT environment variable.
    (missing: TBB_LIBRARIES) (found version "2020.3")
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/local/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    cmake/modules/FindTBB.cmake.in:286 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    cmake/modules/FindTBB.cmake:29 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:384 (find_package)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have installed TBB. If you would notice even this error has the version listed.

Things I have tried:

1. Installing boost, cmake and tbb via brew.
2. Installing boost, cmake and tbb via macports.

Comment: Have you installed TBB? How did you install it? Where is it installed?

Comment: Also, considering that Apple is moving away from Intel CPU's, TBB might not be an optimal and future-proof library to work with on macOS.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I install tbb using brew. I also tried installing using macports. Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
cmake .. -DTBB_LIBRARYDIR=/opt/intel/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8 -DTBB_INCLUDEDIR=/opt/intel/tbb/include
```

Note the subtle differences in the CMake var names and the path to include, not include/tbb.Let me know how that goes